# How do I to get next row's column value in a stored procedure column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help please.

In my final select I want to display the next row's value in `PriceValue` column

Example of my stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    w.ShopID AS shopID,
    w.ProductName AS ProductName,
    w.ProductID AS ProductID,
    w.PriceValue   -- (this logic should be: if w.Type = Outdoor then give the next row's value 
                   -- which would then be **100 000** and **90 000** see image)    
FROM 
    Warehouse w
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: `LEAD` is your friend, although you have to define an order that defines what you consider "next" (ordering on product ID does not seem natural, unless there really is some process that assigns them with deliberation).

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Supplying DDL, input data and desired results _as text_ makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LEAD() (for previous LAG()) function there. ie:

```
SELECT w.ShopID as shopID, w.ProductName as ProductName,
w.ProductID as ProductID,
w.ProductID as w.PriceValue, 
case when Type = 'Outdoor' then 
      Lead(PriceValue, 1, 0) over (Partition by ProductName order by ProductId) else PriceValue end as ModifiedPrice 
from myTable;
```

Note: Your data structure looks weird, that may be a typo.